# Cannot view any content beneath my header div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: screenshot]

I am not sure why I can't view content beneath my navbar.All I get is blank in my in place of the `<h1>Hello</h1>`. Would appreciate some guidance for this code in particular, but also any resources to learn more about how to avoid this problem in the future.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>A random title piece.</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="../static/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

</head>
<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container pull-left">
<a class="brand" href="../">Things and Stuff </a>
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse" id="main-menu">
                    <ul class="nav" id="main-menu-left">
                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                        <li>
                            <form class="form-search">
                                <div class="input-    append">
                                    <input     type="text" class="span2 search-query">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn">
                                        Search
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a id="swatch-link" href="../popular">Example 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a id="swatch-link" href="../sold">Example 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a id="swatch-link" href="../new">Example 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<h1>Hello</h1>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/js/json2.js"></script>


</body>
```

Comment: Removed the span. my style.css doesn't talk to any class in my home.html. (.drawing, .play, .sketch)

Comment: Here is a jsBin (http://jsbin.com/ikedoc/1/edit) with your code. It works fine (in spite of your curious markup. I suppose you are testing or sort of..). Where is that header benith which you cant include content? Everything seems to work fine for me...

Comment: Could it be my bootstrap is causing a problem? I don't understand why mine isn't showing up. I didn't mean header tag, I was referring to my navbar, will fix that above.

Comment: Ok. The navbar. Anyway...the same goes for the navbar. Which is the problem. May be one of your css which I am not using in the JsBin.

Comment: @BenjaminBakhshi Plz check the jsfiddle I provided , also the content goes beneath the navbar coz its fixed and you need to provide positioning of the content

Comment: Take a look at your bootstrap and review your code

Comment: @BenjaminBakhshi did yA CHECK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content is hidden beneath your header .Wrap your content with a div with class container and than let us know .
[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/KF2Hh/) 
[Jsfiddle with padding](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/KF2Hh/1/)

```
<div class=".container">
  <h1>Hellow world</h1>
</div>
```

And add the followingin your css

```
.container > h1
 {
margin-top:70px;

 }
```

Or you can use the following , I suggest using this one :

```
.container > h1{
   padding-top:70px;
 }
```

Comment: Why are you saying .container and not just container?

Comment: I tried that, with ".container" and "container" and that didn't solve my problem.